# arrays con if php

Tags: php

Bueno pues soy algo nuevo y no tengo mucha exp pasa lo siguiente en un arreglo de 3 numeros saber cual es el mayor ,el menor o si son iguales 
pues lo tengo de esta manera no se si sera la correcta o abra una mejor aclaro tengo que hacer esto con las condicionales if,else

```
<?php 
    $numm=array();

    $numm[0]=1;
    $numm2[1]=2;
    $numm3[2]=3;

    if($numm[0]<$numm2[1] or $numm3[2])
    {
        echo "El indice menor es:".$numm[0];

    }
    if($numm3[2] > $numm2[1] or $numm[0])
    {
        echo "El indice mayor es:".$numm3[2];
    }
    else
        {
            echo "todos son iguales";
        }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

No sé por qué pusiste el "or" pero si sólo es con if else, entonces podrías hacer algo así:

***Aclaro algo, no se si te dijeron que puedes anidar los if/else, así que lo haré sin anidarlos.***

```
<?php 
    $numm=array();
    $numm[0]=1;
    $numm[1]=2;
    $numm[2]=3;
    if(($numm[0]==$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]==$numm[2])){
        echo "Todos los numeros son iguales";
    }
    if(($numm[0]<$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]<$numm[2])){
        echo "El menor de los numeros es ".$numm[0];
    }   
    if(($numm[0]<$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]==$numm[2])){
        echo "Hay dos numeros menores iguales a: ".$numm[0];
    }   
    if(($numm[0]==$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]<$numm[2])){
        echo "Hay dos numeros menores iguales a: ".$numm[0];
    }
    if(($numm[1]<$numm[0]) && ($numm[1]<$numm[2])){
        echo "El menor de los numeros es ".$numm[1];
    }   
    if(($numm[1]<$numm[0]) && ($numm[1]==$numm[2])){
        echo "Hay dos numeros menores iguales a: ".$numm[1];
    }   
    if(($numm[2]<$numm[0]) && ($numm[2]<$numm[1])){
        echo "El menor de los numeros es ".$numm[2];
    }   
?>
```

**Correcciones a tu código:**

```
$numm2[1]=2;
$numm3[2]=3;
```

Por:

```
$numm[1]=2;
$numm[2]=3;
```

Razón:

No existen los array numm2 y numm1

Esta parte:

```
    $numm=array();
    $numm[0]=1;
    $numm[1]=2;
    $numm[2]=3;
```

Se puede cambiar por esto, ya que es básicamente lo mismo:

```
    $numm=array(1,2,3);
```

Y hago el cambio de los `or` (tendrías que haber puesto `||` ya que ese es el `or` en php) que usaste por `&&` (and) y compruebo todos los casos posibles.

**Te explico cada if:**

Si todos son iguales:

```
if(($numm[0]==$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]==$numm[2])){
    echo "Todos los numeros son iguales";
}
```

Si el primer número es el más chico:

```
if(($numm[0]<$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]<$numm[2])){
    echo "El menor de los numeros es ".$numm[0];
}
```

Si el primero y el tercero son iguales y son los menores:

```
if(($numm[0]<$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]==$numm[2])){
    echo "Hay dos numeros menores iguales a: ".$numm[0];
}
```

Si el primero y el segundo son iguales y son los menores:

```
if(($numm[0]==$numm[1]) && ($numm[0]<$numm[2])){
    echo "Hay dos numeros menores iguales a: ".$numm[0];
}
```

Si el segundo es el menor de todos:

```
if(($numm[1]<$numm[0]) && ($numm[1]<$numm[2])){
    echo "El menor de los numeros es ".$numm[1];
}
```

Si el segundo y el tercero son iguales y son los menores:

```
if(($numm[1]<$numm[0]) && ($numm[1]==$numm[2])){
    echo "Hay dos numeros menores iguales a: ".$numm[1];
}
```

Si el tercero es el menor de todos:

```
if(($numm[2]<$numm[0]) && ($numm[2]<$numm[1])){
    echo "El menor de los numeros es ".$numm[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php 

    $numeros = [1,2,3];
    $mayor = 0;
    $menor = PHP_INT_MAX;

    foreach($numeros as $item){
      if($item > $mayor){
       $mayor = $item;
      }
      if($item < $menor){
       $menor = $item;
      }
    }
   if($menor === $mayor){
      echo "Todos son iguales";
   }else{
     echo "El menor es: ". $menor;
     echo "\nEl mayor es: ". $mayor;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero pues apenas estoy iniciando y si me preguntan por ejemplo para que el foreach y de donde saco la funcion PHP_INT_MAX porque apenas estamos en las condiciones if/else no hay manera de hacer lo que tu me explicas pero solo usando if/else y gracias.